# How do I get "crypto shell extensions" back in to open with in windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-server, regedit, windows-server-2019

I have installed openpgp and kleopatra. After installing it, most of the certificate file extensions like .p7s, .pem are opening with it. How do I change it back to **crypto shell extensions**?

[image]

I want it like this. You can see, it is showing **Crypto Shell Extenstions**

[image]

Comment: Use “choose another app”

Comment: Examine the (Default) registry value for `HKCR\P7SFile\shell\open\command`.  It may likely need to be changed back to `%SystemRoot%\system32\rundll32.exe cryptext.dll,CryptExtOpenPKCS7 %1`.  Note: `P7SFile` is the (Default) value for the `HKCR\.p7s` file extension.  Repeat these steps for other 'stolen' file extensions.

Comment: @leeharvey1 thanks it worked. please add it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examine the `(Default)` registry value for: `HKCR\P7SFile\shell\open\command`

It can be changed back to:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\rundll32.exe cryptext.dll,CryptExtOpenPKCS7 %1
```

Note: `P7SFile` is the `(Default)` value for the `HKCR\.p7s` file extension.

If necessary, repeat the steps above for any other 'stolen' file extensions.