Windows SSL cert file (.crt, .cer, .pfx, etc.) association with Crypto Shell Extensions is broken
When right-clicking an SSL certificate file in Windows Explorer, you would normally see the option to Install Certificate in the context menu, and you could also view the cert by double clicking the file.  On my system, this file association is broken and I don't see the Install Certificate option and when I double click the file it will just show me a dialog to select a program to use for opening (like it doesn't recognize the file). The option to use Crypto Shell Extensions isn't available, and when I find these file types in the "Choose default apps by file type" utility, there is no Crypto Shell Extensions option shown for the file type.
I'm not sure how or exactly when this happened on my Windows 10 system, but I recently noticed it.  I realize there is another excellent tool called XCA (https://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/) which allows you to view cert files, but I used to have XCA working alongside the Crypto Shell Extensions and wanted to restore this function.
Anyone come across this and know how to fix this association specifically for the .cer, .crt, .pem and .pfx (and other similar) file types?

Do you have "Windows Certificate Viewer" as an option when you go to select a default program in the default associations?

@Abraxas no, I don't see that option even available.

Did you try this? https://superuser.com/questions/1717450/how-do-i-get-crypto-shell-extensions-back-in-to-open-with-in-windows-11

Thanks a lot @Abraxas for the link to that other question.  The info in that post is very helpful and good to know.  Although that was not directly the problem, I think something on my system got messed up and I ended up being able to resolve it by reinstalling the latest version of XCA, and then removing it.  After that, the original behavior is now restored, and I can also select the checkbox to use Crypto Shell Extensions to always open those file types (ie. .crt/.cer).  I think after I reinstall XCA it should work fine this time alongside the Crypto Shell Extensions.

I think something on my system got messed up and I ended up being able to resolve it by reinstalling the latest version of XCA, and then removing it. After that, the original behavior is now restored, and I can also select the checkbox to use Crypto Shell Extensions to always open those file types (ie. .crt/.cer).
As per @Abraxas's suggestion, I found the information in How do I get "crypto shell extensions" back in to open with in windows 11? to also be very valuable and good to know for troubleshooting this type of issue.

I use the following reg to add the default app of .pem to Crypto Shell Extensions.
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pem]
@="CERFile"
"Content Type"="application/x-x509-ca-cert"


